# How to deal with old-school administrators not understanding my methods

Tags: professionalism, education, school

I am a mid-career teacher at a public school in the USA. I'm the most senior and highest-paid teacher in my school and, until recently, was very satisfied with the job. Admin respected me, and largely left me alone, knowing I would get the job done properly and that I knew what I was doing.

Only a few years prior, I quit working at another school in the district that had an overwhelmingly "old-school" staff. Most were above fifty, had almost no teacher training to get their jobs, or were from overseas. Their methods were *very* traditional. I felt suffocated—forced to run a literal late-19th Century classroom. At times they threatened to strip me of my license if I didn't toe the line. When I tried to defend my practice, they assumed what I described was "made up".

This year, the district reshuffled some administrators and the new admin in charge of overseeing my teaching is from the workplace I left. I'm back to where I was before, being scrutinized heavily by someone who assumes I don't know what I'm doing. He uses the evidence that my classroom looks "chaotic" as proof that I need help, when his idea of as sixth-grade classroom is students seated in rows quietly taking notes from a lecturer.

I'm frustrated being back in the prior situation. My solution before was to leave. How can I push back against this situation where I feel I'm being misunderstood?

Comment: It seems to me that your new methods would have some basis in research.  Have you tried educating these administrator on the subject?

Comment: Like it or not, the boss does get to set the rules. Either present evidence and try to convince them to let you demonstrate that your preferred approach works (which may take years), or try to find an employer who agrees with you (which may also take years). Or change careers (which may take years).

Comment: If you are a teacher you are in a union. What does the union say?

Comment: Your very first step would be to find out how hard or how easy it is to get a job in another school that you like. That decides how you can proceed. If you have an administrator who feels that you "need help" and "don't know what you're doing", then you are in your rights to tell him that he is totally out of date and doesn't know what he's doing. Whether you do that depends on the answer to the first question.

Comment: Now if your school was really happy with your methods for years, and someone who comes from an old school doesn't like it, then your union might feel that there is a personal grudge against you at work.

Comment: Many teachers unions can only intervene if the very specific language of the contract has been breached.  In my experience most unions would be unlikely to act against an admin for scrutinizing a teacher.  It would have to get to the point of harassment for them to act, and this doesn't sound like harassment at all.  Most likely outcome is that the admin will just make it so hard on the OP that he/she just decides to walk away

Comment: Have you tried or considered involving the next-up level in the hierarchy? Perhaps someone there can support your methods. On the contrary, if your boss's boss supports your boss's views, you'll have a hard road ahead...

Comment: Did you know this person at your previous job? Were you peers? Is he aware that you quit your job over this methodology disagreement? Did you quit amicably?

Comment: @DJClayworth union membership might be quite likely, but nothing in the question suggests the OP is somewhere that every single teacher is in a union (assuming such a place exists). Even if not in a union they may be in a non-union professional body - they could even be in both - which may help provide evidence but not help fight.

Comment: I'm using "union" to include "non-union professional body", which is the same thing for most purposes. And there are lots of places where every teacher is in a union, with only a few exceptions like teachers in non-accredited private schools.

Comment: Don't want to add to an already large number of comments, but it seems no one asked the obvious: who is the administrator accountable to? Is it the kids' parents perhaps, or a superintendent that oversees your district? It seems you solved your problem once via leaving but repeatedly applying this won't work. Perhaps it's time to try mediation with the third party the admin is accountable to. Remember your greatest asset in mediation/negotiation is how much value you clearly bring to your kids, and that replacing you would deprive them of that value.

Answer (score 44):

There are two important differences between this round with the admin than your previous interaction with them:

### Proof and Evidence

First you have at least a few years of using your teaching techniques.  If those students went through some form of Standards of Learning (SOL) testing and those grades are comparable or better than other students then that can be used as proof that your teaching techniques do not need to change.

If you have any other hard numbers that your students are doing just fine, then document them and show them to the admin.

### Allies

Second are there any other teachers in your current school that also do not conform to this new admin's standards?  Or is there a teacher's union or association that can intervene? If so ask them (fellow teachers or union) to support you and for advice on how to approach and convince this admin.  Also, they may be aware of other avenues to convince this admin to back down.

Comment: Also, parents can be allies as well, especially if there is a board of parents.

Comment: piggy-backing off the parents suggestion - if you have one chummy, gossipy parent who loves your class, and one righteous parent who has to have the best for her precious child, you are one malicious compliance mention of a 19th century ruler away from having them solve this for you.

Comment: @LeLetter Especially if they have younger kids as well. Then they really have incentive to keep the good teachers around.

Answer (score 4):

> How to deal with old-school administrators not understanding my methods?

Schedule a meeting with the administrator so that you can present your case for why you should be allowed to use your methods.  Make sure that the administrator fully understands your method.  If you have any case studies, local examples, or official research that supports your methods, you should bring them with you to present to this administrator.

Keep in mind that the point of this meeting is not to argue with the administrator or to criticize or even comment on their "old school" mentality.  You just need to present the evidence that demonstrates why your method works, how it will benefit the students and the school, and why you should be allowed to use it.

After that, you need to accept the administrator's decision.  At the end of the day, it is their decision to make, not yours.  If you cannot live with your boss making a decision that you disagree with you can always resign as you did in the past but as you have already experienced, moving away from your problems is not always a valid long term solution.

Comment: The principal (administrator) does not determine education policy in every jurisdiction in the USA.  If an administrator is bonkers, they'll get fired; so no, you don't "need to accept" it everywhere.

Comment: You absolutely shouldn't just "accept the administrator's decision", that's a deriliction of duty to the children. Their job isn't to do whatever the admin staff say, their job is to give the children the best possible education.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater Would you say that if OP wanted to teach intelligent design and the administrator didn't want them to? If not, who can judge which one is proper?

Comment: @pipe - Obviously not... And the scientific consensus, backed by rigourous evidence, is what should decide which one proper. Certainly not school administrators.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater The administrator's job is also to ensure that the children have the best possible education and if they feel that one of their employees ( teacher ) is using a methodology that will not give the best possible education it is their responsibility to correct this.

Comment: @sf02 - but if the methodology is well supported by both literature and actual student performance, then the administrator's _feelings_ should be pushed back on.

Comment: @pipe it's not what's being taught that's at issue - that's often decided on the state level. The problem is the way it's being taught. The admin expects the students to sit quietly in their isolated seats, while the teacher has taken a more modern, hands-on, collaborative approach.

Comment: @sf02 - Not really, it's the administration's job to make sure that the school is run in a sustainable fashion and that it functions. The job of actually educating the children should be deferred to suitably qualified teachers.

Comment: @LeLetter We only know what OP believes. OP has not given any indication that his students perform better in any metric (happiness, academic results, etc) and unless you think a classroom can _never_ be too "chaotic" there is also the chance that the administrator is the one more aligned with the current best-practice.

Comment: @pipe I've worked in schools and no, 6th graders no longer work in rows. If the administrator had actual metrics to prove their point, they would have used that instead of a vague accustation of 'chaos'.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater - However, it will be the Administration (team) that will evaluate the teacher's performance, and that performance review, will often decide if that teacher has a job the next year.

Comment: @Donald - And the performance of a teacher should really only be quantified by the progress that their students make under their tutelage.

Comment: @pipe - If the students weren't developing well, the administration would have said "your students are performing poorly" not that his classroom is nebulously too chaotic

Comment: To further expand on my point... I'm an engineer in my full time job and a part time researcher too... If my boss comes to me and tells me to design something dangerous, or even to design something subpar, it's my legal responsibility not to do so. Even if it wasn't my legal responsibility, it would be my moral responsibility as a professional. I see this as being no different, being a teacher and knowingly delivering substandard education is morally wrong.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater - You mean by the fact their students can pass a standardized test? That often is part of their performance review. However, a teacher can literally 
"teach to the test", and the school district and state teaching boards won't know about it.

Comment: A standardised test is hardly the only metric that can be used to guage student progress... Although if "teaching to the test" doesn't actually require the teacher to teach the curriculum well, then you've got a problem with your exam boards...

Comment: As a parent, I like that this teacher is pushing back for better teaching methods.  But I don't know what is best.  Administrators are powerful (and sometimes even right).  If I were in this position, I would look for a new job.